# History in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, laradock

When I use a normal terminal in linux, I can use the up arroy key to navigate between previous command that I executed. I need do the same in a container in docker.

Ex:

Login to the container work space with this command:

```
/usr/bin/winpty.exe docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

Then, In the workspace container I run something command like this:

```
composer self-update
```

And then I close the current session, The next time that I try to repeat the same steps whenever I'm logged in the container, the prompt history doesn't have any commands saved.

I use laradock in windows.

Comment: How did you run your container? post your run command

Comment: Does the output of `history` contain your command before closing the session?

Comment: bash history is stored under ~/.bash_history . Try to cat this file to see if it is empty.

Comment: I ran the container with this command:

docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: The history never saved the command, even without close the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After that I searched more about this problem, I found this reports in git-hub

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13817

https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/183

Finally the problem for me was the client that I used (git-cli). I change to (Powershell) and it works perfectly. Putty it's too an alternative to connect to docker environment.

Comment: Wow, how odd. I was having this problem when using Git Bash on Windows to log into my DigitalOcean server and then into Docker (Laradock). After seeing your post, I tried using Windows PowerShell instead of Git Bash, the the command line history now works. Thanks!